# How to test if grammar is regular (using a library or a framework)?

Tags: grammar, formal-languages

How do I conveniently test if a formal grammar is [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar)?

Basically, I am searching for an existing library or framework which provides such functionality.

A library should be callable from some relatively common language, e.g. C/C++/Python/Haskell. A framework that provides command line utilities for that would be ok as well.

The software should be open source and support some kind of BNF syntax as input.

Comment: I think it is very easy to write a code to validate is grammar is regular.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, yeah ... I think it is very easy to write my own linked list, stack, sort algorithm, topological sort algorithm, red-black-tree, hash-table etc. implementation but I am glad that there is - say - `std::list`, `std::stack`, `std::sort`, boost graph, `std::map`, `std::unordered_map` and so on. It's about not-reinventing the wheel, thus saving time on developing, debugging and testing.

Comment: I agree with Chauhan.. you will spend more time searching and implementing a library than writing your own code you just need to check that there can be (at most) only one non terminal in each production and this non terminal should only be place at the rightmost place of the production.

Comment: @Qsebas, ... your ansatz does not work for left regular grammars, does not work for regular grammars which are not already in normal-form, does not free me from writing a parser and so on.

Comment: its true, it only works for Right Regular Grammars... if you want both flavours you should only detect if it is a Right or Left RG (with the first production with terminals and non-terminals, and then enforce all the other production to have the same behaviour.

Comment: Regarding "wich are not already in normal-form" there is a missunderstanding of the theory. A Grammar is allways regular or non-regular regarding if it has allways only one non-terminal in the right if you use RRG (or in the left if you use LRG). The recognized language by the grammar is another issue, for example you can have a non-regular grammar recognizing a regular lenguaje, I suppose you are reffering on that issue when you are talking about "not in normal form". In this case, there is no way to decide if a non-regular grammar recognize a regular language in a polinomial time.

Comment: Obviously you can have somes methods to TRY to recognize a regular language, but you would never be sure. Even the Pumping Lemma can't be applied in every non-regular language

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Python Code that return if a grammar is regular (working for both right and left regular grammar):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

termials = ['a']
nonterminals = ['S']
grammar = [('S',['a', 'S']), ('S',['a']) ];
regular = True
leftRG = False
rightRG = False
for leftSide, rightSide in grammar:
  for nonterminal in nonterminals:
    if not(leftRG or rightRG):
      if len(rightSide) > 1:
        if (nonterminal in rightSide[0]):
          leftRG = True
        elif (nonterminal in rightSide[-1]):
          rightRG = True
        else:
          regular = regular and not (nonterminal in rightSide)
    if rightRG: 
      regular = regular and not (nonterminal in rightSide[:-1])
    if leftRG:
      regular = regular and not (nonterminal in rightSide[1:])
print regular
```

note: remember that if a non regular grammar recognize a regular language, this routine will return False, as it is impossible to decide regularity in polinomial time.

Comment: You say it is impossible to decide regularity in polynomial time. An even stronger result exists: it is undecidable whether an arbitrary grammar (such as a CFG) recognises a regular language (proof: Greibach's theorem). Cheers!